# How can I quickly embed an email signup form on my website without having to set up a database?

Tags: html, css, forms, email

I'd just like to embed a "If you'd like to know when we launch, please enter your email address below" sign up text box, which I can use to collate the email addresses of interested users.

What is the best way of achieving this?

EDIT: I am currently using Prefinery, but I am unable to change the style of the iframe to match what is currently on my site, so it looks out of place.

Comment: Collate or collect? Just store the addresses in a text file.

Comment: Have you considered using an email newsletter service, like Constant Contact or Mail Chimp?

Answer (score 0):

You can have it write to a text file, then when it's time to send the emails, have it parse the file line-by-line and send the emails, this is probably the most simple solution if you don't want to use a external service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get an invite to [Launch Rock](http://launchrock.com/). I think this might be what you need.